# Rain: Geshem or Matar?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, weather, geshem-tal-ruach

We start praising Hashem for rain on Shmini Atzeret, referring to rain as *Geshem*: וּמוֹרִיד הַ**גֶּשֶׁם**

A few weeks later we start asking for rain and Ashkenazim use the word *Matar* - וְתֵן  טַל וּ**מָטָר** לִבְרָכָה

What's the difference between Geshem and Matar and why do we use one for praising and the other for asking for rain?

Comment: I would assume this is discussed somewhere in מסכת תענית, although I don’t recall

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Rabbeinu Bahya Devarim 11:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Devarim.11.17.2?lang=bi):

> לפעמים המטר יורד מן השמים כלומר ממים העליונים, ולפעמים ממי אוקיאנוס שהן מים תחתונים, ואותו שהוא ממי אוקיאנוס אינו נקרא מטר אלא גשם, מלשון גשמות ודבר גופני, ואותו שהוא ממים העליונים נקרא בשם שניהם בלשון מטר ובלשון גשם‏
>
> [S]ometimes the rain waters originate in the oceans whereas on other occasions they are of celestial origin. The key to understanding the phenomena in question lies in the use by the Torah of two different words for the word rain, גשם and מטר, respectively. The word גשם refers to something physical, i.e. rain originating in the ocean, whereas the rain originating in the celestial spheres is described by using both the name גשם and the name מטר.
>
> *(Eliyahu Munk's translation, available at sefaria.org)*

Malbim builds off this idea and writes on [Bereishit 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Genesis.2.5.1?lang=bi):

> והמטר הוא ענין השגחיי ויורד בזכות האדם ובתפלתו. וכבר בארתי (למעלה א ו) שיש מטר טבעי הבא בסבת האדים העולים מן הארץ וזה נקרא בשם גשם ואין בו ברכה. ויש מטר השגחיי הבא מלמעלה ממים העליונים שזה נקרא בשם מטר וזה יש בו ברכה. ומטר זה לא ירד רק ע"י זכות האדם וע"י תפלתו.‏
>
> מטר is providential, and descends due to a person's merit and prayer. I have already explained above (1:6) that there is natural rain that comes due to moisture evaporating from the earth, and this is called גשם and does not contain blessing. And then there is providential rain which comes from Above, from the Upper Waters, which is called מטר and does contain blessing. And this rain will not descend without a person's merit and prayer.
>
> *(My translation)*

Utilising this idea, I would suggest that when we **ask** for rain, we specifically ask for blessed *matar* (which, per Malbim, only comes as a result of prayer). When we more generally **praise** Hashem for the fact of rain, we use the generic *geshem*, which (per R. Bahya) applies to both types of precipitation.

Answer (score 4):

This exact question was raised by [R. Shlomo Hakohen of Vilna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_HaKohen_(Vilna)) in his notes to the beginning of [Masechet Ta'anit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27anit_(Talmud)), and he offered two answers:

1. *Matar* generally refers to rain that is a blessing, while *geshem* refers to all rain. Thus, when we request rain, we request that it should be rain that is a blessing. When we praise the power of God, though, we refer to all rain (good or bad) because even bad rain is a demonstration of God's power. This explains why in the Prayer for Rain on Shemini Atzeret the phrase משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם is modified with לברכה ולא לקללה — otherwise it would include bad rain as well.
2. In [Berachot 33a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33&format=pdf) we are told that the reason why the praise for rain is in the blessing of the resurrection of the dead is that rain is equal to the resurrection. The verse that the Talmud Yerushalmi derives this from uses the term *geshem*, thus we use the term *geshem* in the corresponding prayer.

**Cheshek Shlomo Ta'anit 2a**

> לכאורה צריך להבין במאי דתקנו לנו רבותינו אנשי כנה"ג לומר בהזכרה בלשון ומוריד הגשם ולא תקנו לומר ונותן מטר כמו דאומרים בשאלה ומאיזה טעם חלקו בין הזכרה לשאלה בזה ובפרט דבקרא דאיוב ה' דמפקינן מיניה דיורדין בגבורה ג"כ מטר כתיב הנותן מטר ע"פ ארץ וגו' וכן מה דסמכו חז"ל על הכתוב דלעבדו בכל לבבכם דצריך להזכיר בתפלה מדכתיב בתריה ונתתי מטר ארצכם ג"כ מטר כתיב ואולי משום דבשאלה דאנו שואלין דיתן לנו טל ומטר לברכה תקנו לומר בלשון מטר דלשון מטר ע"פ הרוב הוא נמצא בפסוק כשיורד לברכה וגם כתיב ביה לשון נתינה ומה דכתיב בקללות יתן ה' את מטר ארצך אבק ועפר התם הכוונה דאם ח"ו יהיו ישראל בגדר אין עושין רצונו של מקום יתהפך לקללה ח"ו אבל בהזכרה דאנו צריכין להזכיר גבורותיו של הקב"ה עדיף טפי לומר בלשון ומוריד הגשם משום דגשם הוא שם כולל לכל מיני גשמים ומשו"ה תקנו לומר בלשון הורדה משום דלשון נתינה אינו שייך כ"כ רק כשיורד לברכה ונ"ל שזהו שיסד הפייטן בתפלת גשם שאתה הוא ה' אלהינו משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם לברכה ולא לקללה והיינו משום דבלשון ומוריד הגשם נכלל בו גם הגשמים שאינן יורדין לברכה ולכן הוצרך לפרש דמ"מ אנו מבקשים שלא ירד רק לברכה ועוד י"ל משום דעיקר הטעם דתקנו לומר גבורות גשמים בתחיית המתים אמרינן בברכות דף ל"ג א משום דשקולה כתחיית המתים ובירושל' שם מפיק לה מהדין קרא דיחיינו מיומים וגו' וכתיב בקרא דבתריה כשחר נכון מוצאו ויבוא כגשם לנו ע"ש וא"כ י"ל כיון דבהך קרא דמפקינן דשקול כתחיית המתים כתיב בלשון גשם ולפיכך תקנו לומר מוריד הגשם וק"ל חשק שלמה
>
> We need to understand that which the Sages, the Men of the Great Assembly, instituted to say when mentioning [rain, to mention it] with the phrase "and brings down the rain (*geshem*)", and did not institute to say "and gives rain (matar)" as we say in the request [for rain, i.e. the ninth blessing of Shemoneh Esrei]. For what reason did they differentiate this between mentioning [rain] and requesting [rain]? And specifically considering that the verse in Job [Chapter] Five from which we derive [in [Ta'anit 2a]](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=2&format=pdf) that rain comes down with power, the term *matar* is written: "who gives rain (*matar*) upon the face of the earth" etc. And also that which the Sages relied on the verse of "to serve him with all your hearts" [as the source] that [rain] needs to be mentioned during prayer, from [the fact] that it is afterwards written "and I will give the rain (*metar*) of your land", there too [the term] *matar* is written.
>
> And perhaps it is because in the request where we ask that He give us dew and rain *as a blessing* they instituted to say it with the term *matar* because the term *matar* is most often found in a verse when [rain] comes down as a blessing, and it is written with the terminology of "giving".
>
> And that which it is written by the Curses, "God will make the rain (*metar*) of your land powder and dust", there the intent is that if heaven forfend Israel will be in the category of "not doing the will of God", [the rain] will be transformed into a curse, heaven forfend.
>
> But by the mentioning [of rain], where we have to mention the might of God, it is better to say it with the phrase "and brings down the rain (*hageshem*)" because *geshem* is a name that includes all types of rain.
>
> And for this reason they instituted to say it with the terminology of "bringing down" because the terminology of "giving" is not really applicable except when it comes down as a blessing.
>
> And it appears to me that this is what the composer established in the Prayer for Rain: "for He is Hashem our God, who makes the wind blow and the rain come down, **as a blessing and not as a curse**", namely that the terminology of "bringing down the rain" includes even rain that does not come down as a blessing, and therefore we are requesting that it should only come down as a blessing.
>
> Additionally, we can answer that the main reason that they instituted to mention the power of rain in [the blessing of] the resurrection of the dead is as articulated in [Berachot 33a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33&format=pdf) that it is equal to the resurrection of the dead, and in the Jerusalem Talmud there it is derived from this verse of "after two days he will revive us" etc. and  in the next verse it is written, "his going forth is sure as the morning and he shall come to us as the rain (*chageshem*)", see there. If so, we can say that since in this verse from which we derive that it is equivalent to the resurrection of the dead it is written with the term *geshem*, they therefore instituted that we say *morid hageshem*.